# Mouse can't Wake Up from sleep my Windows 7 Computer,but keyboard can,Allow this device to wake the computer is checked

Tags: windows-7, mouse, wake-up

I have DFI DK P45 T2RS Plus motherboard and BTC9051H keyboard and Logitech G9x Laser Mouse Call of Duty: MW3 Mouse,use clover(like grub) to boot windows 7 so I don't use hybrid sleep,only pure sleep,Allow this device to wake the computer is checked both keyboard and mouse.
I have entered follow commmand in cmd:

```
C:\Users\cuthead>PowerCfg -DEVICEQUERY wake_armed
HID Keyboard Device
Logitech HID-compliant G9x Laser Mouse Call of Duty: MW3
HID Keyboard Device (003)
HID Keyboard Device (005)
Marvell Yukon 88E8053 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller
```

seems like G9x should able wake up my computer.But when I wake up from sleep by click or move mouse,nothing happened,I press keyboard and wake up properly.How to let my mouse wake up my computer?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your Device Manager - are there other mouse devices (like "HID Mouse Device ...")? If yes - allow them to wake up your PC too.
2. Check USB HUBs at Device Manager - disallow them to be turned off to reduce power consumption.

Comment: Looks like it's a ACPI DSDT problem,because I use OSx86 and need DSDT UHCI patch to wake up from sleep for Yosemite.